# How can I find the address of a stack trace in LLDB for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, lldb

When I get a crash report, the offending part of my code will sometimes look like this, instead of showing me the actual line number, even though the crash report is symbolicated:

```
-[ViewController myMethod:] + 47
```

In order to debug this, I need to know what line of my code this represents so that I can visually inspect it, set a breakpoint, etc.

What is a good way to get the address of a method plus offset, as shown above, using LLDB?

NOTE: this question is NOT a duplicate of [how to read a crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13411510/1804403). I know how to read a crash report. I am asking very specifically how to get the corresponding line using LLDB. Nothing in the other answers shows how to do that. They are quite verbose and go into all kinds of things about dealing with crash reports and debugging in general, but don't show what the specific steps on LLDB are. Please do not duplicate this bug.

Comment: I'm about to give you a terrible answer, but viable in tight situations. Convert that number to decimal, then divide by the bus bits. I'll call that "the number of instruction-lines I have to traverse". Of course, there's another offset based on what exactly is stored between things. I had 2020, ended up being 128. So basically "a ways down". I found an area that wasn't guarded properly, and it basically helped me fix my crash. Guesstimation

Answer (score 15):

[note this ONLY works if you save Archives in XCode of all the builds you released]

Information you need to collect first:

- **APPNAME**: the short name of your app as seen in the Archive directory (typically the XCode Target name; you will see it immediately when you look at the Archive directory in Finder below).
- **CRASHING_FUNCTION_NAME**: name of function shown in useless Apple backtrace (in the OP's example, `-[ViewController myMethod:]`)
- **ARCH**: architecture of device that crashed.  Most likely the right value is either `armv7` or `arm64`.  If you don't know, try both.

Ok here are the steps:

1. In XCode go to Window...Organizer...Archives
2. Right-click on the Archive for the release the crashing user has, and choose Show in Finder
3. open a Terminal shell and `cd` to that directory shown in Finder
4. execute the following in the shell:

   ```
   lldb -arch ARCH Products/Applications/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
   ```
5. inside lldb do the following:

   ```
   (lldb) add-dsym dSYMs/APPNAME.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/APPNAME

   (lldb) disassemble --name CRASHING_FUNCTION_NAME
   ```
6. you now see a rich disassembly with symbols, and lo and behold, each line shows the same decimal offset as the original useless Apple backtrace (in the OPs example, the useless offset was `47`), as in:

   ```
   APPNAME[0xf4a7c] <+47>:  ldr    r0, [r0, r1]
   ```
7. you might be able to figure out the corresponding source line just from this information, if the disassembly has enough symbols to help you figure out where you are.
8. if not, there is another great trick.  Pass the address of the line that crashed:

   ```
   (lldb) image lookup -v --address 0xf4a7c
   ```
9. Now `lldb` shows you a rich collection of information---**much richer** than what is shown by Apple stack backtraces even when they do contain line numbers, and much richer than lldb `source list`---about all the source lines that contributed to the assembler instruction at that address.  Pay close attention to both the `Summary` and `LineEntry` sections.  Example:

   ```
   Address: APPNAME[0x000f4a7c] (APPNAME.__TEXT.__text + 963740)
   Summary: APPNAME`myclass::myfunc(bool, bool) + 904 [inlined] std::__1::deque<mystruct, std::__1::allocator<mystruct> >::operator[](unsigned long) + 22 at myfile.cpp:37945
            APPNAME`myclass::myfunc(bool, bool) + 882 [inlined] myinlinefunc(int) + 14 at myfile.cpp:65498
            APPNAME`myclass::myfunc(bool, bool) + 868 at myfile.cpp:65498
   Module: file = "/Users/myuser/mydir/arch/Products/Applications/APPNAME.app/APPNAME", arch = "armv7"
   CompileUnit: id = {0x000483a4}, file = "/Users/myuser/mydir/myfile.cpp", language = "objective-c++"
   Function: id = {0x0045edde}, name = "myfunc", range = [0x000f46f4-0x000f572a)
   FuncType: id = {0x0045edde}, decl = myfile.cpp:65291, compiler_type = "void (_Bool, _Bool)"
   Blocks: id = {0x0045edde}, range = [0x000f46f4-0x000f572a)
           id = {0x0045f7d8}, ranges = [0x000f4936-0x000f51c0)[0x000f544c-0x000f5566)[0x000f5570-0x000f5698)
           id = {0x0046044c}, ranges = [0x000f49c6-0x000f49ce)[0x000f49d6-0x000f49d8)[0x000f4a2e-0x000f4a38)[0x000f4a58-0x000f4a82), name = "myinlinefunc", decl = myfile.cpp:37938, mangled = _Z11myinlinefunci, demangled = myinlinefunc(int)
           id = {0x00460460}, ranges = [0x000f4a58-0x000f4a64)[0x000f4a66-0x000f4a82), name = "operator[]", decl = deque:1675, mangled = _ZNSt3__15dequeI12mystructNS_9allocatorIS1_EEEixEm, demangled = std::__1::deque<mystruct, std::__1::allocator<mystruct> >::operator[](unsigned long)
   LineEntry: [0x000f4a7c-0x000f4a82): /Applications/Xcode7.3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/deque:1678:14
   Symbol: id = {0x00000805}, range = [0x000f46f4-0x000f572a), name="myclass::myfunc(bool, bool)", mangled="_ZN7myclass7myfuncEbb"
   Variable: id = {0x00460459}, name = "myvar1", type = "int", location =     , decl = myfile.cpp:37938
   Variable: id = {0x0045f7dd}, name = "myvar2", type = "bool", location =  , decl = myfile.cpp:65583
   Variable: id = {0x0045edf2}, name = "this", type = "myclass *", location =  [sp+56], decl =
   Variable: id = {0x0045ee01}, name = "myvar3", type = "bool", location = , decl = myfile.cpp:65291
   Variable: id = {0x0045ee0e}, name = "myvar4", type = "bool", location = , decl = myfile.cpp:65292
   ```
10. In this example under `Summary`, we can see that the line that crashed was actually a combination of code from `myclass::myfunc()`, `myinlinefunc()` and `std::deque::operator[]`.  This kind of mashing together is very common for optimized code.  This is often enough information to find the offending source line of your code.  Under `LineEntry` we see the line number for the most-nested code contributing to that assembler line, which in this case is in the STL `std::deque` code, but in other cases might be the exact line number you want in your code.
11. Now the only remaining question is: why **on earth** doesn't Apple just do this for us in the original backtrace?  They clearly have all this information themselves!  Why do they make us jump through such hoops?  What are they hiding?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: this is very useful answer! thank you! how can I use it with swift? `disassemble —name SwiftClass.foo()` says "unable to find symbol with name ..."

Answer (score 11):

Here is something I found that worked:

First you need to find the address of the method itself.

```
image lookup -v -F "-[ViewController myMethod:]"
```

in the result you will see a lot of info, but the range part will give you want you want

```
... range = [0x000708c0-0x00070c6c) ...
```

(where 0x000708c0 is address of method)

Now to add the given offset of 47, just use LLDB to do that math for you:

```
(lldb) p/x 0x000708c0 + 47
(int) $0 = 0x000708ef
```

and you get your answer, the offending line is on 0x000708ef

Or better yet, based on Jason Molenda's answer, is to just go straight to the code listing, which will show the line number:

```
(lldb) source list -a `0x000708c0 + 47`
```

EDIT: improved based on the answer from Jason Molenda

Answer (score 11):

Your steps (`image lookup` + `p/x addr + offset`) will give you the raw address, as you found.  But the original crash report probably included an address before the method + offset --- it is just as easy to slide your binary to the correct address using `target modules load`.  At the end of the crash report there should be a list of the binary images present in the program, including load address and UUID.

But more importantly, while the address is nice what you're really after is the source location.  In that case, once you've determined the correct address for the method (or slid it to the matching address via `target modules load`), you can use `source list`

```
(lldb) so l -a `addr + offset`
```

I'm using the backtick notation here which does an in-line expression evaluation.  There's a handy shortcut for most commands that take an address: if you omit spaces, you can write the expression without backticks:

```
(lldb) so l -a addr+offset
```

You can also use `image lookup` with an address.  If you have debug information, this will tell you what the current location of variables are at this point.  Why is this useful?  Because most crash reports include the register context at crash and so any variables that are currently in a register are provided to you (`-v` is necessary to get all of the register location information).

```
(lldb) im loo -v -a addr+offset
```

Finally -- this isn't going to work because you're dealing with an Objective-C method name -- but with a simple C function name you can do the offset arithmetic in-line as long as you cast the function name to a pointer type (it's not legal C to add an offset to a function pointer).  e.g.

```
(lldb) so l -a (char*)main+10
```

Comment: When I run an app in XCode, and do this command: 

im loo -v -a $pc

I get output that shows variables, but I don't see anyway to match those to what is in the registers. It lists their position but not what might be in register. 

     Variable: id = {0x000000a4}, name = "self", type= "ViewController *const", location = DW_OP_fbreg(8), decl = ViewController.m:30

so I don't seem to be getting any "register location information". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah yes, the location descriptions are in the DWARF expression language, I forgot to mention that.  "fbreg" means "frame base reg", lldb gives you a "$fp" register alias which will probably be the right thing.  If you are debugging a 32-bit process (arm, Simulator) you'd do `x/x $fp+8` - if you're debugging a 64-bit process (x86_64) you'd do `x/gx $fp+8` to see the value.  `$fp+8` is an address of stack memory, the `x` command (an alias for `memory read`) reads 4 bytes (`x`) or 8 bytes(`gx`) of memory at that address.

Comment: Since image lookup will not tell you which variables are being stored in registers, then I guess we should remove the comment about using the register context from the crash report. Maybe there are other ways to do that, but that is really beyond the scope of the question anyway. Do you mind if I edit your answer to remove that part?

Comment: Also, I am not clear on how I can slide my binary using target modules load. Once I am running the app on a device, it is too late to slide, right? Or are you doing things from the command line somehow? I tried to find a description of how to do this and could not.

Comment: Please do not edit the answer to say that the `image lookup` doesn't say what registers variables live in.  For unoptimized programs they tend to have canonical locations on the stack (the `fbreg + offset` stuff) but in an optimized program they will only live in registers.  If you're debugging a live process (it sounds like you are), you don't need to set the load address of your binaries via `target modules load` - lldb will get the correct load addresses from the dynamic link loader (dyld) automatically.  `ta mo loa` is only needed for static (not-running) crash tracer analysis.

Comment: Can you explain how to use `target modules load` for static crash analysis?  I see the command expects a "file" or "UUID" but do not know which file/UUID it wants.  Also, I tried to use `source list` many times but `lldb` kept showing me the source code from a completely unrelated part of my source file, despite showing the correct function name and address and despite `image lookup -v --address 0x...` showing the correct function names, as seen in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41859283/1046167) to this question.  Could this be related to not doing `target modules load` ?