# -[User length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc7b60143e0'

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

I have the following code and receive the error code indicated in title:
This is the only messages i send to User object (other than initialising it by using "new")
When I out comment addObject: it doesn't complain.
Can anybody help? Thanks!

```
self.freshUser.name = self.name.text;
self.freshUser.age = (int)self.age.text;
self.freshUser.gender = self.gender.text;

//NSLog(@"%@",[NSThread callStackSymbols]);
[appDelegate.users addObject:self.freshUser];
```

(My user object subclasses NSObject. it has more property that I don't use. just a little extra info)

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewPara cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UserCell *cell = [tableViewPara dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:usersTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  if(indexPath.row == [appDelegate.users count]){
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"+";
    cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36];
    cell.bgImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_gray"];
    cell.statusImg.image = nil;
  }else{
    cell.nameLabel.text = appDelegate.users[indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
    cell.bgImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_dark_red"];
    cell.statusImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cloud"];
  }
  cell.nameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  cell.nameLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  cell.nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

  return cell;
}
```

space

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff1bf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fbb4bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff2304d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe7b27c ___forwarding___ + 988
4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe7ae18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x00000001104d034b -[UILabel _setFont:] + 101
6   Raymio                              0x000000010f67857f -[StartViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 991
7   UIKit                               0x00000001103ff4b3 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 508
8   UIKit                               0x00000001103defb1 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2846
9   UIKit                               0x00000001103f4e3c -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
10  UIKit                               0x0000000110381973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113c09de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
12  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113bfea0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
13  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113bfe87e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
14  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b6c63e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b6d74a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000113b6ddb5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe50dc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe50d20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe46b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe46486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
21  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001134fd9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
22  UIKit                               0x0000000110308420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
23  Raymio                              0x000000010f678a83 main + 115
24  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001124ab145 start + 1
```

Comment: Please post the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in your `StartViewController` class.

Comment: The `(int)self.age.text` will not work. That's not how you convert a text string to integer. Instead, call `[self.age.text intValue]`. But that's not likely to be the source of your error. That suggests that you used an object of class `User` somewhere where it was expecting a string (or maybe an array).

Comment: @Rob Hmm, actually I did try to make freshUser.age an NSString earlier with no difference. I didn't get any issues using my way, I changed it to your way, still no issue (but ill keep it if thats the proper way) Nevertheless, thats not the issue I'm getting the error code for. Thx for the heads up though

Comment: So, what is line 991??

Comment: (I see you finally decided you need the exception stack trace.)

Comment: I'm guessing that this line is line 991: `cell.nameLabel.text = appDelegate.users[indexPath.row];`.  And the reason it's failing is that `appDelegate.users[indexPath.row]` is returning a User object, not a NSString.  All this can be gleaned from 30 seconds looking at the readily available exception info -- it's only a mystery if you refuse to actually *look* at the info.

Comment: @DevilInDisguise There are two completely different problems here. One is the error in your crash, which kpsharp solved for you below (you stored a `User` object in the array, but when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieved the object from the array, rather than treating it like the `User` object it is, you tried using it as a string in the label field, which generates the error of your title of this question). The second, completely unrelated issue is how to grab a text string of the age and extract the integer value, and your `(int)` cast won't do that, while `intValue` method will.

Comment: @hotlicks I wonder what you are doing in my threads other than voting down and brining feisty comments, because Im a rookie. There are many much dumber questions available that doesn't get the same hostile treatment. I try my very best to solve a question before posting. I do not have much knowledge about debugging yet, hence my failure(yes I did not know how to use the exc. stack trace properly, more flame?). Thanks for the thumbs down though, appreciate it

Comment: You wondered why we needed the exception stack trace.  I told you.  Had you put the full exception and stack trace in your original question it would not have been beat up so badly.

Comment: And note that by programming iOS/Objective-C you are essentially claiming to be an "experienced" programmer, not a rank novice.  A programmer with experience knows the importance of error messages, exception stack traces, etc, and knows how to pose a proper question here, with the appropriate code segments, error info, etc.  When you say you're using Objective-C the assumption rightfully that you know these things.

Comment: @HotLicks Im not claiming anything. And yet again here you go with the spicy comments. If you had asked me to put those things in my original question, instead of just posting a one-line hostile comment without clearness, it would've been there. All the posts I looked at when trying to search for an answer did NOT include the trace stack (4/5 did, I checked now), none of those were attacked as hostile as you did, nor were they down voted. Good job being the unfriendly person you are.

Comment: Oh, and btw, since the solution to my latter question was simple, apparently, to make a custom class subclassing NSObject conform to <NSCopying> before being able to add it to an NSMutableArray, I would think any "experienced" programmer would know this, and state the answer instead of throwing around feisty comments without useful help (Obv due to your down votes and finger pointing no one will get help from that thread). Over and out of this madness (you can be happy you got to down vote me twice without proper reason).

Comment: @HotLicks You suggested that he look at line 991. Unfortunately, 991 is not a line number. You have to (a) get the address via `image lookup`; and (b) then use `source list` to show the offending line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112842/how-can-i-find-the-address-of-a-stack-trace-in-lldb-for-ios. Its more complicated than your "look at line 991" statement suggested, but its an invaluable technique (look at stack trace, scan back for the first reference to something in our own code, and then use this technique to show the line of code that likely started the whole thing).

Comment: @Rob - It depends on how you get the stack trace and (I suspect) on whether you're in debug mode.  Looking at it again you're right that that trace looks like the crash dump that doesn't have line numbers, but you can get the line numbers if you use the right technique.

Comment: The simple way would be to add an exception breakpoint. That nicely brings you to the line where the crash happened; at least that helped me in this case. Thanks for the link rob, Ill have a look into that. When 991 is not a line number (which confused me when I was told it was), what is it then?

Comment: @DevilInDisguise It's an "offset" (in bytes, I presume) in decimal. When you lookup the symbol, such as `-[StartViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`, you'll get a range of addresses. If you add that offset to the start of the range of addresses, the `source list` command will take you to that line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = appDelegate.users[indexPath.row];
```

You're trying to set a `User` object to the text of a label field. That's not going to work. You'll want this or something close:

```
cell.nameLabel.text = ((User *)appDelegate.users[indexPath.row]).name;
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why the following doesn't work: (User *)appDelegate.users[indexPath.row].name;(without the extra "()") Btw Do I always have to prefix a call to an array with the content type of the array? (And lastly, was it because CellForRowAtIndexPath came after "-[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205" in the trace, that u suspected thats where the issue was?) I appreciate it a lot! Will brb

Comment: That's called a cast. You're basically saying it should be a specific type of object instead of what might have been expected (so in this case, `id` is returned, but you need `User`). Casting it the way you said is trying to cast the name property, not the object in the array. Think order of operations in arithmetic. ObjC doesn't support generics, so everything is basically assumed to be an `id`. That means you'll need to cast it in order to access properties on it. Yes, that was the last bit of code that you would have written that was in the stack trace.

Comment: Your help has been tremendous. Thank you very much! You really deserve 2votes (as u might have suspected from the code snippet). Thanks again, Ill get some sleep now:)(...wondering how in the world I could get a vote down on my question...haters will hate)

Comment: Sure thing! While I don't agree with that guy's methods, he wasn't wrong - your last question was lacking some details, but you'll notice we got a lot further, a lot quicker with this question. Keep structuring your questions like you did this one, and you'll get a lot more out of SO. Have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

You shared your stack trace with us. A useful technique is to look in it for anything that references code you wrote. You may notice that line 6 references your `StartViewController`:

```
6   Raymio                              0x000000010f67857f -[StartViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 991
```

You can show the relevant line of code by typing `source list` command using that address in the third column:

```
(lldb) source list -a 0x000000010f67857f

   43        cell.nameLabel.text = @"+";
   44        cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36];
   45        cell.bgImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_gray"];
   46        cell.statusImg.image = nil;
   47      }else{
-> 48        cell.nameLabel.text = appDelegate.users[indexPath.row];
   49        cell.nameLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
   50        cell.bgImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_dark_red"];
   51        cell.statusImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_cloud"];
   52      }
```

Clearly your line numbers and memory addresses will vary, but hopefully this will illustrate the idea. Scan the stack trace for anything that references your code, and examine that line of code for any potential issues.

By the way, [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112842/how-can-i-find-the-address-of-a-stack-trace-in-lldb-for-ios). also shows you how to use the `-[StartViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 991` of the stack trace to show the relevant line of code.