# XCode Symbolicated Crash report, get line number instead of memory offset

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging, crash-reports

I have a symbolicated crash report of my application.

Some lines of the backtrace are like this. The line number is shown correctly, which is really useful:

```
TopicMapScene::create(int) (TopicMapScene.cpp:588)
```

But some lines are like this. The line number is not displayed, just a memory offset, which is not useful.

```
cocos2d::CCSequence::update(float) + 206
```

My Question: How come the line number is sometimes displayed, sometimes not? Is there a solution to make the line numbers displayed instead of the memory offsets? (Or it is just simply not possible, and I should make smaller functions to tackle this?)

Comment: I do not know why on earth Apple sometimes shows useless offsets instead of line numbers, but here is how you can map the useless offsets back to source line numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859283/1046167