# How to find exactly where a crash occurred from an Xcode crash log?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, crash

So I have this log of a crash. From what I can gather my function from the DateTimeHelper gets an object that it doesn't expect and tires to execute a function on it that that object does not have.

I can't reproduce the problem so I don't know exactly where inside the function it is. Can I some how find out from the crash log? Does the byte offset from the function’s entry +176 help? Does the address of the machine instruction that is executing help? I don't know how to use those two numbers if at all relevant.

```
0   CoreFoundation                  0x24c0f916 __exceptionPreprocess + 122 (NSException.m:162)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x243aae12 objc_exception_throw + 34 (objc-exception.mm:531)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x24c152b0 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 184 (NSObject.m:333)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x24c12edc ___forwarding___ + 696 (NSForwarding.m:3149)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x24b3e234 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 20 (NSForwarding.s:641)
5   MyApp                           0xc83c4 +[DateTimeHelper dateFromServerFormat:withLocale:andTimeZone:] + 176
```

Why is there no file and line number for MyApp frame? Is it some kind of privacy concern? The crash log is from Organizer reports. I remember previously being able to click on the function in the organiser and it send me to the exact place. Now it is not working dunno if it is the new  Xcode 12.0 (12A7209) that broke it. It only opens the stack in Xcode and nothing more.

Comment: Do you have the .dSYM for the build that crashed? If so you could probably use `atos` to find the line number.

Comment: A previous user suggested that I symbolicate the crash. I thought the crash was symbolicated as seen that there are function names and not addresses in it. Apple however didn't provide the file and the line of code which apparently you should get manually your self....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's auto symbolicate doesn't provide the file and line of code where the crash happened.

Per comment suggestions I symbolicated the code. From the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/adding_identifiable_symbol_names_to_a_crash_report#3403800) using atos:

```
atos -arch <BinaryArchitecture> -o <PathToDSYMFile>/Contents/Resources/DWARF/<BinaryName>  -l <LoadAddress> <AddressesToSymbolicate>
```

[Find your DSYM](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/adding_identifiable_symbol_names_to_a_crash_report#3403787) file for the version that crashed. Usually can be found in the archived version if your build is set to add a DSYM or you could download it from Apple if it was uploaded. Use this image to replace the rest of the templates:
[image]

After replacing the place holders it should look something like this:

```
atos -arch arm64 -o TouchCanvas.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/TouchCanvas -l 0x1022c0000 0x00000001022df754
ViewController.touchesEstimatedPropertiesUpdated(_:) (in TouchCanvas) + 304
```

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41859283/2870783) is a very helpful post.

Do have in mind that in some situations, the file name or the line number information won’t correspond to the orginial source code. The code might be compiler generated not in your source files or the compiler might have optimised your source in which case optimised code lines may not correspond to source.