# iOS crash log does not contain line number and can not find symbol using disassemble

Tags: ios, crash, crashlytics, lldb

I got some crash logs from Crashlytics. Like

```
App -[Socket init:queue:] + 508
App -[SocketK recv:error:] + 5508
App xxx_accept + 5296
App xx_accept + 1680
App xx_input + 48
```

I found the solution from [How can I find the address of a stack trace in LLDB for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112842/how-can-i-find-the-address-of-a-stack-trace-in-lldb-for-ios/41859283#41859283) to get the real position.

When I use `disassemble  --name` to find the symbol, it may or may not work. For example, I can find the `xxx_accept`  but can not find the `-[Socket init:queue:]`.

So why does it not work? and how to get the crashed position?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash log files have to store the list of loaded binaries at the time of the crash, and their load addresses.  The process of "symbolicating" a crash log involves finding the debug info (dSYM's) for the app, and assigning them the appropriate addresses to form a recreation of the crash state, then querying this recreation for address->symbol name translations.

I am not very familiar with crashlytics, but if they use the standard Apple format for crash logs, then this references might help:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding-identifiable-symbol-names-to-a-crash-report

and this WWDC session:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10211

might also be useful.  At least they will give you some context.

If crashlytics has some other format for crash logs, then presumably they will provide some tools to symbolicate their crash log format as well.  Maybe look in their support fora for more details?

Comment: My question is why lldb cannot "disassemble to find" the symbol, not how to deal with the crash log. I have to check the assembler to find the problem, because the symbolicated crash log is not enough. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The instructions in the answer you cite only refer to loading the main module, so you will only be able to disassemble names from that module.  To see other symbols, you'll have to find the other binaries from the crash log, add them to the debug session and then you will be able to disassemble from those libraries. `image list` will show you what binaries you currently have loaded in lldb so you can check.

Comment: Thanks. I finally found the symbols with `nm`. The symbols are affirmative in binary, maybe I didn't use lldb correctly.